# Unified Date format with no reliance to the server/system

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, localization

I have an ASP.NET / C# web site i'm building,
in one of the pages i'm asking the user to choose a date with a date picker of my own which send the date to my code-behind in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

The problem starts when the site is online, my computer is using the "dd/MM/yyyy" format and the server uses the "MM/dd/yyyy" format, so when i try to convert the date received in the code-behind to a DateTime type using "Conver.ToDateTime()" on my own PC it works just fine, but when the site is online, if the date is for example "14/05/2015" it will cause an 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' error, since it's trying to convert it to a format which causes it to be an illegal date (5th day of 14th month).

What's the best elegant solution for this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the date in a fixed format, like ISO (`yyyy-MM-dd`). If all parties use the same format, there will be no ambiguity.

Comment: The problem is when using the built in function of Convert.ToDate(), it's trying to convert my string in a "MM/dd/yyyy" format.

Comment: You can use DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: @argamanza I've never been a fan of the `Convert` class. Using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can specify the date format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a specific `CultureInfo` or format string to all of your date parsing and `ToString()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the best experience formatting the date with ISO format.  It is well-defined and can't possibly get confused.

For example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("o")
```

This will produce:

```
2015-07-04T16:56:54.2508072+01:00
```

To be double-sure, you can always parse it back this way:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateAsStr, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```